# Programmatically scroll a range of EditText into view

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have a large `EditText` used to enter code. It can scroll horizontally (deliberately nested in `HorizontalScrollView`) and vertically along with the rest of the page within `ScrollView`. I also have error highlighting functionality: when a user presses Preview or Save, the code is validated and errors are highlighted using `BackgroundColorSpans` like this:

```java
Editable text = mConfig.getText();
for (OverlayValidator.ValidationError error : errors) {
    text.setSpan(
            new BackgroundColorSpan(error.isCritical ? 0x40FF0000 : 0x40FF8800),
            error.errorStart, error.errorEnd,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE | Spanned.SPAN_INTERMEDIATE
    );
}
```

Now I want to focus on an arbitrary error, i.e. scroll it onto the screen if it's currently off the screen. A widely suggested solution for this on StackOverflow is to force a selection on the desired range:

```
Selection.setSelection(mConfig.getText(), errors.get(0).errorStart, errors.get(0).errorEnd);
```

This indeed works, and the range scrolls itself into view ([video here](https://gfycat.com/MassiveSoupyBantamrooster)), however, as said on the tin, it highlights the range, which is undesirable.

I can avoid the selection by specifying only one position to place the cursor, like this

```
Selection.setSelection(mConfig.getText(), errors.get(0).errorEnd);
```

but this will only ensure that the cursor enters the screen, and the rest of the range may remain off-screen ([another video](https://gfycat.com/IndelibleFrighteningGecko)).

Trying to call both results in only the last selection command taking effect, even if I call them like this:

```
Selection.setSelection(mConfig.getText(), errors.get(0).errorStart, errors.get(0).errorEnd);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Selection.setSelection(mConfig.getText(), errors.get(0).errorEnd);
    }
});
```

Basically I need `Selection`'s side effect (scrolling into view) without actual selection.

I tried to examine the code to understand how the selected range gets summoned on the screen, but the code was too tangled (spans, watchers, and all that stuff) and I couldn't figure it out. From the docs I came across the method `View.requestRectangleOnScreen(Rect)`, but how do I obtain the rect to scroll to? (I could always take the `TextPaint` and measure the characters myself, but there must be a better way!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved it back then but forgot to post the answer.

You can obtain the coordinates of your desired substring by calling `getSelectionPath(start, end, outPath)` on TextView's `Layout` object and then request those into focus. For example, I subclassed `TextView` and added this method:

```
// ...    
private Path mTempPath = new Path();
private RectF mTempRectF = new RectF();
private Rect mTempRect = new Rect();
// ...

public void requestFocusRange(int start, int end) {
    final Layout layout = getLayout();
    if (layout == null) {
        // probably rotating the screen, do nothing
        return;
    }

    layout.getSelectionPath(start, end, mTempPath);
    mTempPath.computeBounds(mTempRectF, false);
    mTempRectF.roundOut(mTempRect);

    // Fix the coordinates origin
    final int paddingLeft = getTotalPaddingLeft();
    mTempRect.offset(paddingLeft, getTotalPaddingTop());

    // Unnecessary - I'm just adding extra spacing to the focused rect
    mTempRect.inset(-paddingLeft, -paddingLeft);

    requestRectangleOnScreen(mTempRect, false);
}
```